# .grid() isn't centering my widget by default in Tkinter (Python)

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

equa = ""
equation = StringVar()

calculation = Label(root, textvariable = equation)

equation.set("23 + 54")

calculation.grid(columnspan = 4)

def btnPress(num):
    global equa
    equa = equa + str(num)
    equation.set(equa)

Button0 = Button(root, text = "0", command = lambda:btnPress(0))
Button0.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

Button1 = Button(root, text = "1", command = lambda:btnPress(1))
Button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1)

Button2 = Button(root, text = "2", command = lambda:btnPress(3))
Button2.grid(row = 1, column = 2)

root.mainloop()
```

Whenever I run my code, .grid() doesn't automatically center my buttons. I've read that .grid() is suppose to automatically center widgets, but I'm not sure if there is something that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: We need a bit more information, because "center my buttons" can mean several different things. Since the window comes up as the exact size to fit the buttons, they currently look centered to me. Can you please try to explain a bit more about what you expect? Are the buttons supposed to be centered horizontally? Vertically? Should they grow and shrink when the window is resized?

Comment: When I run the code, the buttons get stuck to the left side of the window and don’t move, even when I resize the window.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you resize the window? Do they grow? Do they stay the same size? Do they stay in the middle, with all extra space around the edges?

Comment: Yeah I thought they were suppose to stay in the middle of the window, no matter how you resize the window or how much empty space there is around them.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the `grid` geometry manage only uses as much space as it needs, and no more. When you resize the window, all of the extra space goes unused unless you tell  `grid` how to use it.

Rows and columns have a `weight` attribute which tells `grid` how to use extra space. Extra space is given to every row and/or column that has a positive weight. the weight is proportional, so a column with a weight of 2 will get twice as much extra space as a column of weight 1.

If you want the buttons to take up all extra space, give each column the same weight. If you want them to be centered, give weight to empty columns along the edges. The same goes for rows and extra vertical space.

You give give columns weight with the `columnconfigure` method of the master widget.  In your case that is the root window.

### Examples

To have the buttons evenly spaced, add the following lines of code:

```
root.grid_columnconfigure((0, 1, 2), weight=1)
```

[image]

If you want the buttons themselves to expand and fill the extra space, use the `sticky` attribute to cause them to stick to the edges of the columns:

```
Button0.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky="ew")
Button1.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky="ew")
Button2.grid(row = 1, column = 2, sticky="ew")
```

[image]

If you want the buttons to remain in the center, give all of the weight to empty columns with the following code:

```
calculation.grid(row=0, column=1, columnspan = 3)
Button0.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="ew")
Button1.grid(row=1, column=2, sticky="ew")
Button2.grid(row=1, column=3, sticky="ew")
root.grid_columnconfigure((0, 4), weight=1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: thank you! was looking for a proper example with `grid` for like an hour!